# File exists but, Status 404 File not Found in master page of asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, path, master-pages, file-not-found

I am giving the JavaScript file path perfectly in master page of asp.net but then also in browser console showing the error of status 404 in JavaScript path i.e. in short the browser not getting the path of the JavaScript file.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index/analytics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/waypoints.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/owl.carousel.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/viewportchecker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/transit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/jquery.simpleslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/backstretch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index/classie.js"></script>
```

Now this JS file is in index folder only, but then also I really confused that why browser console showing this type of error that status:

> 404 javascript file not found.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try using something like the ResolveUrl() method to reference your jQuery library to ensure that it is targeting the proper location :

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/index/jquery-1.10.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```